# tomcat manager with ldap authentication

Tags: tomcat6

I have gone through other questions of stackoverflow but none seems to resolve my issue with configurating tomcat with ldap for manager access.
Here is what I have done

1. Configured JNDIRealm with ldap config.
2. Manager application deployed on tomcat.

I'm able to validate that user authentication is successful however the logs complain that there is no role associated.

```
2017-04-25 14:17:54,644 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase-   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTMLManger and Manager command]' against GET /html --> true
2017-04-25 14:17:54,644 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase-   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[HTMLManger and Manager command]' against GET /html --> true
2017-04-25 14:17:54,644 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase-  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
2017-04-25 14:17:54,644 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase-   User data constraint has no restrictions
2017-04-25 14:17:54,644 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase-  Calling authenticate()
2017-04-25 14:17:54,648 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm- Attempting to authenticate user "manager" with realm "org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm/1.0"
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm- Authenticated user "manager" with realm "org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm/1.0"
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase- Authenticated 'manager' with type 'BASIC'
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase-  Calling accessControl()
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase-   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[manager()]
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase- Different realm org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm@2eeb0945 org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm@4af37bb8
2017-04-25 14:17:54,667 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase- Username manager does NOT have role manager
2017-04-25 14:17:54,668 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase- No role found:  manager
2017-04-25 14:17:54,668 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase-  Failed accessControl() test
```

Note: I have validated that manager role exists in manager/WEB-INF/web.xml and also I have a ldap attribute called tomcatRole=manager. I have userRoleName="tomcatRole" in server.xml for the JNDIRealm config.

What part of configuration am I missing ?

Version: tomcat6
LDAP: OUD

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue. The ACI's were missing on the ldap server due to which the tomcat process couldn't find the role on ldap. Added new aci's which resolved the issue.